# Eclipse CDT Plugin not recognizing std namespace in certain files

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, toolchain

I've just installed Eclipse and the CDT (C++) plugin, and I'm having the strangest problem.

From a fresh C++ Project, the automatically generated "Hello World!" program works just fine. However, upon creating a new C++ Class in the very same project, namespace std is not recognized. I invoke the namespace with the same syntax in both files, but the compiler is throwing this error -

```
"error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'"
```

I've restarted both Eclipse and my computer, but the problem persists. So far as I can tell, the properties of both files are exactly the same. 
I suspected this had something to do with the tool chain, but it is the same in both of the files. I really can't find any difference between the two files, other than their size and date created.

Comment: Your program probably didn't `#include` any headers that define the namespace `std`.  Also, post the program you did try.

Comment: Weird, that did it! I added "#include <iostream>" to the offending files and it fixed up all the problems. I was using std:: to invoke the namespace, and I assumed that would do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: ok.  I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program probably didn't `#include` any headers that define the namespace `std`.  Please add the appropriate `#include` files that define the `std` namespace.